# How do I modify the source code for pos_tag in NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk

I am working on a project for an NLP class and am working with a corpus and some of the words are being tagged incorrectly. Does anyone know how to modify the source code (or obtain it) for part-of-speech tagging so I can play with and correct it?

-Emily

Comment: https://github.com/nltk/nltk

Comment: Or, better just go to the NLTK homepage and click the "Development" link and it will take you to wherever the source repo happens to be (which is of course on GitHub today, but could be elsewhere in 5 years). The same thing works on almost all open source projects.

Comment: you can have a 'friendly' fork if you want to, or contact the devs directly and contribute to NLTK

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know how to modify the source code

Yes. As with almost every open-source project, there is a link directly to the source code from the front page. In this case, it's the "Development" button on the navbar on the right side. Click it, and it will take you to the repo. The same link is also in the documentation for the installed package. [The repo](https://github.com/nltk) is on GitHub today, but if it ever moves in the future, the homepage will almost certainly change to point to the new location.

Once you get to the nltk repo (or nltk3-alpha, if you're using the alpha version), fork it, clone it, and then you can find the source locally. You can guess that `nltk.tag.pos_tag` will be in the `nltk/tag/` directory, most likely either in `__init__.py` or in some other module it `from foo import`s from, or you can just use `grep`, `ack`, the "Find in Files" menu item in your favorite IDE, etc. to find the function.

Whether you want to maintain your own fork that nobody else will be interested in, or to submit patches upstream, the great help at GitHub will explain how to do that.